# what is the right format of -adaptresourcefilenames in ProGuard

Tags: resources, proguard

I have an application JAR file I would like to obfuscate using ProGuard. It contains "AppName\resources" folder and several "ClassName.properties" files in it.
What is the right format of -adaptresourcefilenames option in my config file  to adapt the properties files to classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option `-adaptresourcefilenames` expects the resource files names to start at the same root directory level as the class names. E.g., it can rename `mypackage/MyClass.properties` (without any directory prefix) corresponding to
the obfuscated name of `mypackage/MyClass.class` (also without any directory prefix).

In this case, you could work on the unzipped application, specifying the input and output directories so the relative paths correspond again:

```
-injars  input(!AppName/resources/**)
-outjars output

-injars  input/AppName/resources
-outjars output/AppName/resources
```